# Formatting into a Matrix form

Tags: c#, string, parsing, matrix, split

I try using the code they have on msdn: it uses foreach and that puts each element on a different line.

**How would I put it into a 3x3 matrix format?**

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' ,'[' ,']', ';', '"', 'A', '=' };

string text = "A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9]";
System.Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

foreach (string element in words)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(element);
}

// Keep the console window open in debug mode.
System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do that.

**1.**

At first your example will output

> 17 words in text:

This is because when you split string by all of the specified chars you get many empty strings, to get rid of them add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option to `Split` method.

```
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now you will get

> 9 words in text:

You can get 3 x 3 matrix with simple `for` loop, like

```
string[,] matrix = new string[3, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) 
    {
        matrix[i, j] = words[i * 3 + j];
    }
}
```

However you need to know number of rows and columns (or assume that the matrix is square).
The method will look something like this

```
public static string[,] GetMatrix1(string text, int n, int m) 
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' ,'[' ,']', ';', '"', 'A', '=' };
    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    string[,] matrix = new string[n, m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) 
        {
            matrix[i, j] = words[i * m + j];
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

**2.**

Another way is to split text by `[` and `]` first, then by `;` to get rows and at last by  (space) to get elements in each row.

```
char[] delimiter1 = { '[', ']' };
char[] delimiter2 = { ';' };
char[] delimiter3 = { ' ' };
string[][] words = text.Split(delimiter1)[1]
                       .Split(delimiter2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(x => x.Split(delimiter3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                       .ToArray();
```

There you will get `string[][]`, number of columns may vary for each row, but if you want `string[,]` type you need to convert it.
As the result the implementation will be like this one

```
public static string[,] GetMatrix2(string text) 
{
    char[] delimiter1 = { '[', ']' };
    char[] delimiter2 = { ';' };
    char[] delimiter3 = { ' ' };
    string[][] words = text.Split(delimiter1)[1]
                           .Split(delimiter2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           .Select(x => x.Split(delimiter3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                           .ToArray();

    string[,] matrix = new string[words.Length, words[0].Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = words[i][j];
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```